# What is a "monomeric polypeptide"?

Tags: protein-structure

In the sentence: "Bacteriophage (viral) polymerases are typically monomeric polypeptides".

I know that polypeptides are chains of amino acids monomers. But what is a "monomeric polypeptide" and what other kinds of polypeptides are there?

Comment: You're right to highlight this confusing statement. As David's answer points out, this is a case of tautology. The term "monomer" or "single polypeptide chain" would be more appropriate I believe. It's a very minor point though and the sentence does technically make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Monomer* in this context means the protein has only one polypeptide chain. In some  proteins, after the individual chains have folded into their 3D or tertiary structure, they associate (generally non-covalently) into a higher order or quaternary structure. A protein with a quaternary structure containing  two copies of the same chain would be called a homo-dimer. One with one copy of each of two different chains is a hetero-dimer.

Haemoglobin is a well-known example of a protein with quaternary structure — it has two copies of the alpha- and two of the beta- chain. Further elementary treatment can be found in [Berg *et al.*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22550/) and explanation of the nomenclature in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_quaternary_structure).

Monomeric *polypeptide* is somewhat misleading in the sentence quoted. Monomeric *protein* would have probably been better as you wouldn't be likely to say ‘dimeric polypeptide’, given that polypeptide implies a single chain.

Comment: A small doubt: What would you call mature insulin? It has two polypeptide chains covalently linked via disulphide bonds. It is a monomeric protein, however.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I wouldn't use my first sentence as a definition of monomer, just as an explanation of what the writer meant. In talking about insulin I personally would say that although it has two polypeptide chains it consists of a single globular subunit and therefore cannot be said to have quaternary structure (as I would define it). This is easy to justify since we now know that the general tertiary structure of insulin is formed by the folding of a single polypeptide chain, proinsulin, which is cleaved to activate it (with a small but significant change in tertiary structure).